# Display "Choose Option" label in Django ModelForm ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django ModelForm ChoiceField and would like to display the text "Choose option" in the dropdown when user visits page. ("Choose option" wouldn't be an actual "value" rather just a "label")

Any thoughts how I can add this to my code below?

I appreciate the time.

```
class ExerciseForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExerciseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        exercises = Exercise.objects.all().order_by('name')
        exercise_choices = [(exercise.youtube_id, exercise.name) for exercise in exercises]
        self.fields['exercise'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=exercise_choices)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [label argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label), like:

```
self.fields['exercise'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=exercise_choices, label="Choose option")
```

Or if you would like it present inside the dropdown without being an actual choice then insert it as the first option:

```
exercises = Exercise.objects.all().order_by('name')
exercise_choices = [(exercise.youtube_id, exercise.name) for exercise in exercises]
exercise_choices.insert(0, (u"", u"Choose option"))
self.fields['exercise'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=exercise_choices)
```

Comment: I've tried that but didn't work. To be more specific I'm trying to have "Choose Option" inside the dropdown menu. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try `empty_label="Choose option"` in your `forms.py`:

```py
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Brands.objects.all(), required=False, empty_label="Brands"
    )
```